# OpenStreetMaps Local Server: Mapnik not Rendering Tiles

Tags: openstreetmap, mapnik

**Introduction:** I've built a local OSM server following this guide https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-14-04/. I've gotten through the guide just fine, and the server appears to be rendering because when I type:

```
  <my server addr>/osm_tiles/0/0/0.png
```

I get the picture of the world as described in the guide.

**The Problem:**
I loaded my gis database with data of Indiana, when I test the same file with the coordinates of Indiana like so:

```
 <my server addr>/osm_tiles/10/41/-85.png
```

I get *404 Not Found*.

I then typed this for more information:

```
 <my server addr>/mod_tile
```

and get:

```
NoResp200: 7
NoResp304: 0 
NoResp404: 0
NoResp503: 0
NoResp5XX: 0
NoRespOther: 0
NoFreshCache: 0
NoOldCache: 0
NoVeryOldCache: 0
NoFreshRender: 7
NoOldRender: 0
NoVeryOldRender: 0
NoRespZoom00: 0
NoRespZoom01: 1
NoRespZoom02: 1
NoRespZoom03: 1
NoRespZoom04: 0
NoRespZoom05: 1
NoRespZoom06: 0
NoRespZoom07: 0
NoRespZoom08: 0
NoRespZoom09: 1
NoRespZoom10: 0
NoRespZoom11: 2
NoRespZoom12: 0
NoRespZoom13: 0
NoRespZoom14: 0
NoRespZoom15: 0
NoRespZoom16: 0
NoRespZoom17: 0
NoRespZoom18: 0
NoRespZoom19: 0
NoRespZoom20: 0
NoTileBufferReads: 7
DurationTileBufferReads: 899
NoTileBufferReadZoom00: 0
DurationTileBufferReadZoom00: 0
NoTileBufferReadZoom01: 1
DurationTileBufferReadZoom01: 152
NoTileBufferReadZoom02: 1
DurationTileBufferReadZoom02: 106
NoTileBufferReadZoom03: 1
DurationTileBufferReadZoom03: 74
NoTileBufferReadZoom04: 0
DurationTileBufferReadZoom04: 0
NoTileBufferReadZoom05: 1
DurationTileBufferReadZoom05: 105
NoTileBufferReadZoom06: 0
DurationTileBufferReadZoom06: 0
NoTileBufferReadZoom07: 0
DurationTileBufferReadZoom07: 0
NoTileBufferReadZoom08: 0
DurationTileBufferReadZoom08: 0
NoTileBufferReadZoom09: 1
DurationTileBufferReadZoom09: 194
NoTileBufferReadZoom10: 0
DurationTileBufferReadZoom10: 0
NoTileBufferReadZoom11: 2
DurationTileBufferReadZoom11: 268
NoTileBufferReadZoom12: 0
DurationTileBufferReadZoom12: 0
NoTileBufferReadZoom13: 0
DurationTileBufferReadZoom13: 0
NoTileBufferReadZoom14: 0
DurationTileBufferReadZoom14: 0
NoTileBufferReadZoom15: 0
DurationTileBufferReadZoom15: 0
NoTileBufferReadZoom16: 0
DurationTileBufferReadZoom16: 0
NoTileBufferReadZoom17: 0
DurationTileBufferReadZoom17: 0
NoTileBufferReadZoom18: 0
DurationTileBufferReadZoom18: 0
NoTileBufferReadZoom19: 0
DurationTileBufferReadZoom19: 0
NoTileBufferReadZoom20: 0
DurationTileBufferReadZoom20: 0
NoRes200Layer/osm_tiles/: 7
NoRes404Layer/osm_tiles/: 0
```

I've also tried reloading Indiana's data and restarting the server with no success.

Comment: i have the same problem but i don't know what i can do?
After http://192.168.88.14/mod_tile i have this: NoResp200: 0
NoResp304: 0
NoResp404: 220
NoResp503: 0
NoResp5XX: 0
NoRespOther: 0
NoFreshCache: 0
NoOldCache: 0
NoVeryOldCache: 0
NoFreshRender: 0
NoOldRender: 0
NoVeryOldRender: 0
NoRespZoom00: 0
NoRespZoom01: 0
NoRespZoom02: 0
NoRespZoom03: 0
NoRespZoom04: 0
NoRespZoom05: 0
NoRespZoom06: 0
NoRespZoom07: 0
NoRespZoom08: 0
NoRespZoom09: 0
NoRespZoom10: 0
NoRespZoom11: 0
NoRespZoom12: 0
NoRespZoom13: 0
NoRespZoom14: 0
NoRespZoom15: 0
NoRespZoom16: 0
NoRespZoom17: 0
NoRespZoom18: 0
NoRespZoom

Answer (score 2):

OSM tile names are not latitude and longitude. See https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames for algorithms to convert between the two.

For a random tile within Indiana try 12/1066/1553 (see http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/12/1066/1553.png
).

You might want to use a viewing software that generates the tile names automatically, for example OpenLayers.